# programmatic dropbox sharing

Tags: bash, node.js, curl, dropbox, dropbox-api

Are there any option through out the dropbox api namely the REST version, to programmatically exercise the sharing options or has anyone invented or discovered a unique approach to this using unix or nodejs  command line tools? curl, etc, etc

I basically want to invite people to dropbox folders through scripts/command line and also accept invitations through scripts/command line.

Right now, to accept invitations you have to click 2 links, one in an email and then one within your dropbox web interface.

And in order to invite, one must login dropbox, click the folder you want to share and then enter an email and click a button.

I would like to do all this in simple 'ol terminal.

Answer (score 1):

The Dropbox API currently does not offer any calls for managing shared folders (e.g., creating, accepting, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I've just released this little gem to do this using the web interface: https://github.com/Jesus/dropbox-invite

The proper way would be doing it through the API but since there's no official implementation I had to build a workaround.